# Best ubuntu/linux distro for latitude d620 ( school, light browsing)

Tags: wireless, multiple-monitors, netgear, distro-recommendation

I'm new to Linux and I want to know which Ubuntu/Linux distro I should use to get the best experience. I'll mainly use it for school work and light browsing (YouTube, Google) It should be easy to use and smooth. I have tried ubuntu 12.04 but I had problems with the WiFi, so I don't think that one will work out right.

If its not too much asked, It should look all right too (not Windows 98 style) and it should be compatible with multiple-monitors because I want to connect an external monitor to the laptop.

Dell latitude d620 specs:

- Intel Core Duo T2300 1.6GHz processor
- 2GB of DDR2 memory

Comment: Sorry for the grammar mistakes but English is not my native languege

Comment: That's OK, that is why we edit your questions, so that you can find out how to add code samples and bullet points etc. Just click on the `edit` link under any post to see how things are formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Every linux distro works because they can be customized to fit your needs. You might want to take a more lightweight distro your laptop, I would suggest trying [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I really want to know why these distros are supported for only a short amount of time, are these not stable enough?

Answer (score 0):

Specially for school there is this distribution: edubuntu

available at: http://www.edubuntu.org/

Your Dell Latitude is not too old but dual-Core - can be - it works better with 32-Bit-image than with 64-Bit-image.

So Lubuntu would be not inmediately necessary - because your Latitude is not "too old".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! edubuntu looks good! I hope this time, it works with my wireless usb dongle.